# Return value of inserted row

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I need to return the value of an inserted record to pass to code to open a form.  How do I get that value?  Code below adds a record and refreshes a datagridview.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnection1 =
                 new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=***.**.***.**,****;Initial Catalog=newCityCollection_Aracor;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=4456r;Password=654935749653");

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT PropertyInformation (ClientKey) VALUES (1)";
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

sqlConnection1.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlConnection1.Close();

this.propertyInformationDataGridView.Invalidate();
this.propertyInformationDataGridView.EndEdit();
this.propertyInformationDataGridView.Refresh();
this.newCityCollectionDataSet.AcceptChanges();
this.propertyInformationTableAdapter.Fill(newCityCollectionDataSet.PropertyInformation);
```

Comment: This is a little hard to understand. Can I get some more context ?

Comment: What `value` are you talking about?

Comment: I am using a Datagridview on a form as a case management tool to select records.  I want to be able to add the record and immediately open a form.  I know how to open the form and what not but no idea how to retrieve the PK of the newly created record.  So hit button, create record, retrieve PK then open record in form is what I am going for.

Answer (score 4):

Change your SQL to something like:

```
INSERT PropertyInformation (ClientKey) VALUES (1);
SELECT * FROM PropertyInformation WHERE RecordID = scope_identity()
```

scope_identity() should give you the last inserted identity column (record ID) for the current session, which will be the ID for the row you just inserted into PropertyInformation.

Comment: better to use scope_identity() function, because @@IDENTITY might be changed by something like trigger.

Comment: Okay how would I pull the value out of the query?  For instance I would do something like                 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT PropertyInformation (ClientKey) VALUES (1)";
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CaseNumberKey FROM PropertyInformation WHERE RecordID = @@IDENTITY";
                cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

Comment: @korrowan if **CaseNumberKey** is a simple value (generally int/long) you can use `ExecuteScalar()` to execute the insert and retrieve that value.  Otherwise (or if you need more than one column) you'll need to treat the command like a query and pull data back into a DataSet.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you wrap such an operation in a sproc.  Have it return the new record's ID as an `OUT` var.

```
CREATE PROC CreateRecord(@ID INT OUT, @Value1 VARCHAR(100), @Value2 VARCHAR(100))
AS BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MyTable (Field1, Field2) VALUES (@Value1, @Value2)
    SET @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
```

...you can then retrieve the OUT param in your `SqlCommand`'s `Parameters` property.  Personally, I like to have this wrapped up in a method; here's what I use for synchronously executing a sproc with parameters, simplified slightly:

```
public static Dictionary<string, object>  ExecSproc(string connectionString, string proc, IEnumerable<SqlParameter> parameters)
    {
    SqlCommand  command = null;
    try
        {
        SqlConnection  connection = GetConnection(connectionString);

        // Build the command
        command                = new SqlCommand(proc, connection);
        command.CommandTimeout = TimeOutSeconds;
        command.CommandType    = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        // Append parameters
        SqlParameter  retValue = new SqlParameter("Return value", null);
        retValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
        command.Parameters.Add(retValue);
        if (parameters != null)
            foreach (SqlParameter param in parameters)
                command.Parameters.Add(param);

        // GO GO GO!
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // Collect the return value and out parameters
        var  outputs = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (SqlParameter param in command.Parameters)
            if (param.Direction != ParameterDirection.Input)
                outputs.Add(param.ParameterName, param.Value);
        return outputs;
        }
    finally
        {
        if (command != null)
            {
            command.Cancel();  // This saves some post-processing which we do not need (out vars and a row count)
            command.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's what it looks like in use:

```
var  results = SQL.ExecSproc(connectionString, sprocName, "@Success OUT", false, "@InVar1", 123, "InVar2", "ABC");
if ((bool)results["@Success"] == false)
    throw new ApplicationException("Failed.");
```

Comment: Do I need a reference to run this.  I use system.data but it appears this needs something else.